# Is an external light meter necessary for photographers?

Tags: canon, lighting

I was wondering if a light meter ([Digital Light Meter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/200-000-Digital-Light-Meter-Luxmeter-Lux-FC-Meters-Luminometer-Photometer-ES9P-/370828220065?pt=US_Light_Meters&hash=item56571596a1)) is necessary when you are about to take a picture. I'm going to buy a Canon EOS and the webpage says that the camera has an embedded light sensor to [give you a recommended value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcwmE.jpg). So, is there any reason to use a photometer?

Comment: @mattdm - You beat me to it by 7 seconds. :)

Comment: @Arthur - Does the question linked by Matt answer this for you? As a short answer: no, it's not needed. However, as the linked question shows, there are advantages to them but I think you'll probably want to learn with your camera first though.